# Get to specific tabView object from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, appdelegate

Trying to launch a specific tabView object from the app delegate when you receive a notification, however the app crashes on launch.

Here is the code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController;
CustomTabViewController  * tabBar = [[CustomTabViewController alloc] init];
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];


NSString *type = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"type"];

if([type isEqualToString:@"friend"]){

    tabBar.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


}

if([type isEqualToString:@"message"]){
    tabBar.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It crashes if the app hasn't been opened before.

Comment: No, the specific crash. You need to give more info on it if you want help.